# Cordova-plugin-camera doesn't work in Android version 4 with IONIC

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I am trying to take a picture from my gallery with cordova camera but it doesn't work, when I select a picture and return to my app, it returns me empty, here's my code:

```
var options = {
  quality: 75,
  destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
  sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
  mediaType: 2,
  saveToPhotoAlbum: false
};
$cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function (imageURI) {

  //Error ocurrs here, imageURL always is empty. IT OCCURS ONLY IN ANDROID VERSION 4.

  $scope.profileImageUrl = imageURI;
  $scope.newImage = imageURI;
  $scope.newImageName = imageURI.split("/").pop();

  var extension = $scope.newImageName.split(".").pop();
  if(extension == "png" || extension == "jpg" || extension == "jpeg") {
    if(ionic.Platform.isAndroid()) {
      /* Managing the path of the file in android */
      if(imageURI.substring(0,7) != "file://") {
        imageURI = "file://" + imageURI;
      }
    }
    if (ionic.Platform.isIOS()) {
      /* Managing the path of the file in iOS */
    }

    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(imageURI, function(fileEntry) {
    fileEntry.file(function(myFile) {
      $scope.fileToUploadMime = myFile.type;
      $scope.uploadProfile();
    }, function(error) {
      console.log("This file doesn't have a Type " + error);
    });
  }, function(error) {
    console.log("Could not resolve File Path" + error);
  });
  } else {
    alert("Only images can be uploaded. Please select an image");
  }
}, function (err) {
  // An error occured. Show a message to the user
  console.log(err);
});
```

Error ocurrs at the beginning of $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function (imageURI), imageURL is always empty. IT OCCURS ONLY IN ANDROID VERSION 4.

Comment: console error trace?

Comment: it doesnt report an error, the bad behavior is that imageURI return from the function $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function (imageURI)  is always empty, just in android v4

Comment: in imageURI It should show you the path of the image taken so make sure to do it or try in any another device

Comment: yes it works in other version of android for example version 5, but just in version 4 it returns imageURI empty